# I need help Returning a string representation of my circular queue

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to returns a string representation of my circular queue heres what I have so far. (Im not allowed to use/import other libraries in my code)

```java
public class A2KeyesOwenQueue {
    private int front;
    private int rear;
    private int numItems;
    private int[] myArray;

    public A2KeyesOwenQueue() {
        // the default size of the queue is 10
        myArray = new int[10];
        numItems = 0;
        front = 0;
        rear = 0;
    }

    // Adds one element to the rear of the queue. Returns true if successful, false
    // otherwise
    public boolean enqueue(int elements) {
        if (numItems < 10) {
            myArray[rear] = elements;
            rear = (rear + 1) % myArray.length;
            numItems++;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    // Removes and returns the element at the front of the queue
    public int dequeue() {
        int temp;
        if (numItems == 0) {
            return -9999;
        }
        else
            temp = myArray[front];
        front = (front + 1) % myArray.length;
        numItems--;
        return temp;
    }

    // Returns without removing the element at the front of the queue
    public int peek() {
        if (numItems == 0) {
            return -9999;
        }
        else
            return myArray[front];

    }

    // Returns true if the queue contains no elements
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (numItems == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    // Returns the number of elements in the queue
    public int size() {
        return numItems;
    }

    // Returns a string representation of the queue
    public String toString() {
        String arr;
        arr = "[";
        if (numItems > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i < numItems; i++) {
                arr = arr + myArray[i] + ", ";
            }
            arr = arr + myArray[0] + "]";
        }
        else {
            arr = arr + "]";
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

My `public String toString( )` doesn't return the right numbers on my test driver. I think it has something to do with it not circling the array.

```
public String toString( ){
String arr;
arr = "[";
if (numItems > 0){
  for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i < numItems ;i++) {
   
    arr = arr + myArray[i]+", ";
  }

  arr = arr + myArray[0] + "]";
}
else{
  arr = arr + "]";
 }return arr;
}
```

And my driver:

```java
/*
 * This class performs test cases for queue
 * 
 * */
class DriverTest2{

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int myMark = 0;
        // TEST 1 
        // (1 mark) A queue is empty on construction
        A2KeyesOwenQueue  q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        if (q.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 1 successfull: +1");
            myMark=myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 1 failed********************");
        }
        // TEST 2
        // (1 mark) A queue has size 0 on construction
        if (q.size()==0) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 2 successfull: +1");
            myMark=myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 2 failed********************");
        }
        // TEST 3
        // (3 mark)After n enqueues to an empty queue, n > 0,
        // the queue is not empty and its size is n
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue (); // reset queue
        for (int i = 100; i < 150; i+=10) {
            System.out.print ("enqueuing " + i);
            if (q.enqueue(i)) {
                System.out.print("... success");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("... failed");
            }
            System.out.println ();
        }
        if (!q.isEmpty() && q.size()==5) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 3 successfull: +3");
            myMark=myMark + 3;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 3 failed********************");
        }
        // TEST 4
        // (2 mark) If one enqueues x then peeks, the value returned is x, but the size stays the same
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue (); // reset queue
        // insert 5 elements 1000 900 800 700 600
        for (int i = 1000; i > 500; i-=100) {
            System.out.print ("Trying to enqueue :" + i);
            if (q.enqueue(i)) {
                System.out.print("... success");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("... failed");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        q.enqueue(100);
        int myPeek = q.peek();
        if (q.size()==6) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 4 part 1 successfull: +1");
            myMark=myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 4 part 1 failed********************");
        }
        if (myPeek == 1000) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 4 part 2 successfull: +1");
            myMark = myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 4 part 2 failed********************");
        }

        // TEST 5
        // If one enqueues x then dequeues, the value dequeued
        // is x.
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue(); // reset queue
        q.enqueue(3);
        int temp = q.dequeue();
        if (temp == 3) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 5 successfull: +1");
            myMark = myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 5 failed********************");
        }
        // TEST 6
        // (2 mark) If the size is n, then after
        // n dequeues, the stack is empty and has a size 0
        // reset the queue
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        // insert 5 elements 1000 900 800 700 600
        for (int i = 1000; i > 500; i -= 100) {

            System.out.print("Trying to enqueue :" + i);
            if (q.enqueue(i)) {
                System.out.print("... success");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("... failed");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            q.dequeue();
        }
        if (q.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 6 successfull: +2");
            myMark = myMark + 2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 6 failed********************");
        }
        // TEST 7
        // (1 mark) call peek() with one item
        // reset the queue
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        q.enqueue(50);
        int temp7 = q.peek();
        if (temp7 == 50) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 7 successfull: +1");
            myMark = myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 7 failed********************");
        }

        // TEST 8
        // (1 mark) call peek() from an empty queue
        // returns -9999 representing no such element
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        int temp8 = q.peek();
        if (temp8 == -9999) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 8 successfull: +1");
            myMark = myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 8 failed********************");
        }
        // TEST 9
        // (1 mark) call dequeue() from an empty queue
        // returns -9999 representing no such element
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        int temp9 = q.dequeue();
        if (temp9 == -9999) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 9 successfull: +1");
            myMark = myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 9 failed********************");
        }
        // TEST 10
        // (1 mark) call dequeue() on an queue with one item.
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        q.enqueue(50);
        int temp10 = q.dequeue();
        if (temp10 == 50) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 10 successfull: +1");
            myMark = myMark + 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 10 failed********************");
        }
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue(); // reset queue
        // TEST 11 enqueue elements until full plus one more element
        boolean t11 = false;
        for (int i = 100; i < 200; i += 10) {

            System.out.print("\nTrying to enqueue :" + i);
            if (q.enqueue(i)) {
                System.out.print("... success");
            }
        }
        if (!q.enqueue(210)) {
            System.out.println("... failed");
            System.out.println("\nTest 11 successfull: +1");
            t11 = true;
            myMark = myMark + 1;
        }
        if (!t11) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 11 failed********************.");
        }
        // TEST 12
        // (2 mark) If one enqueues the values 1 through 10, in order,
        // into an empty queue, then if 10 dequeues are done the values
        // dequeues are 1 through 10.

        // reset the queue
        System.out.println("\nTest 12.");
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        int i;
        // insert 10 elements 1 through 10
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            System.out.print("Trying to enqueue :" + i);
            if (q.enqueue(i)) {
                System.out.print("... success");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("... failed");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        boolean t12 = true;
        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i == q.dequeue()) {
                System.out.println("Dequeued expected element");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The element expected was not what was recieved");
                t12 = false;
            }
        }
        if (t12) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 12 successfull: +2");
            myMark = myMark + 2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nTest 12 failed********************");
        }

        // TEST 13
        // (1 mark) print all elements in queue when front < rear
        // reset the queue
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        // insert 7 elements 50 51 52 53 54 55
        for (i = 50; i < 56; i += 1) {

            System.out.print("Trying to enqueue :" + i);
            if (q.enqueue(i)) {
                System.out.println("... success");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("... failed");
            }

        }
        int stringOutput = 0;
        System.out.println("\nTEST 13"); // (1 mark)
        String myQ, yourQ;
        System.out.println("The elements in queue according to Mr. Corea:");
        myQ = "[50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]";
        yourQ = q.displayQueue(); //toString();
        System.out.println(myQ);
        System.out.println("The elements in queue according to You:");
        System.out.println(yourQ);
        System.out.println("MATCH: " + myQ.equals(yourQ));
        if (myQ.equals(yourQ)) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 13 successfull: +1");
            stringOutput += 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Test 13 failed********************");
        }
        // TEST 14 print all elements in queue when rear < front
        // reset the queue
        q = new A2KeyesOwenQueue();
        // insert 10 elements 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
        for (i = 50; i < 60; i += 1) {

            System.out.print("Trying to enqueue :" + i);
            if (q.enqueue(i)) {
                System.out.print("... success");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("... failed");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // dequeue 5 elements
        q.dequeue();
        q.dequeue();
        q.dequeue();
        q.dequeue();
        q.dequeue();

        // enqueueing 3 more
        q.enqueue(60);
        q.enqueue(61);
        q.enqueue(62);
        System.out.println("\nTEST 14"); // (2 mark)
        System.out.println("The elements in queue according to Mr. Corea:");
        myQ = "[55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62]";
        yourQ = q.displayQueue(); //toString();
        System.out.println(myQ);
        System.out.println("The elements in queue according to You:");
        System.out.println(yourQ);
        System.out.println("MATCH: " + myQ.equals(yourQ));
        if (myQ.equals(yourQ)) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 14 successfull: +2");
            stringOutput += 2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Test 14 failed********************");
        }

        // dequeue 2 elements
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println(q.dequeue());
        System.out.println("\nTEST 15"); // (2 mark) print an empty queue
        System.out.println("The elements in queue according to Mr. Corea:");
        myQ = "[]";
        yourQ = q.displayQueue(); //toString();
        System.out.println(myQ);
        System.out.println("The elements in queue according to You:");
        System.out.println(yourQ);
        System.out.println("MATCH: " + myQ.equals(yourQ));
        if (myQ.equals(yourQ)) {
            System.out.println("\nTest 15 successfull: +2");
            stringOutput += 2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Test 15 failed********************");
        }
        System.out.println("TEST RESULTS: " + myMark + " /17 plus " + stringOutput
                + "/5 for correct toString()");

    }
}
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the body of method `toString()` that returns the correct result.
(Notes after the code.)

```java
String arr = "[";
if (numItems > 0) {
    if (rear == front) {
        arr += myArray[front];
    }
    else {
        int limit;
        if (rear > front) {
            limit = rear;
        }
        else {
            limit = 10;
        }
        boolean first = true;
        for (int i = front; i < limit; i++) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                arr += ", ";
            }
            arr += myArray[i];
        }
        if (rear < front) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rear; i++) {
                arr += ", ";
                arr += myArray[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
arr += "]";
return arr;
```

Since the queue is circular, the start of the queue starts at `front` and extends to `rear`.

If `rear` is equal to `front`, that means that the queue contains only a single element.

If `rear` is greater that `front`, that means the the queue is not full, i.e. less than ten elements have been added to the queue.

If `rear` is less than `front`, it means that `myArray` is full, i.e. contains ten elements, and so you need to print all the elements from `front` to the last element of `myArray` and then you need to print the first elements of `myArray` starting from the first element up to `rear`.

For example if `myArray` is as follows:

```
[60, 61, 62, 63, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
```

and `front` equals 5 and `rear` equals 4, then `rear` is less than `front` so the first `for` loop in the above code will append the values from 55 to 59 and the second `for` loop will append the values from 60 to 63.

Note that I only changed method `toString`. I did not change any of the other code in your question. When I ran your test cases, this was the last line of the output.

```
TEST RESULTS: 17 /17 plus 5/5 for correct toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code appends `myArray[0]` twice, this should fix the your issue

```
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder arr;
    arr = new StringBuilder("[");
    arr.append(myArray[0]);
    if (numItems > 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10 && i < numItems; i++) {

            arr.append(", ").append(myArray[i]);
        }

        arr.append("]");
    } else {
        arr.append("]");
    }
    return arr.toString();
}
```